# NextJS 13.4 layout : Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: next.js, layout, navbar, next.js13

[I tried to implement Navbar as header throughout the whole application. So I called Navbar component before children in layout.tsx and it shows these errors. I am a beginner in NextJS so I'm not being able to understand the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncxem.png)

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Navbar from './Navbar/Navbar'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'SN Mart',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({children}:{children: React.ReactNode}){
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Navbar/>
      <div>
        <body className={`${inter.className} `}>{children}</body>
      </div>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Inside the Rootlayout I called Navbar component but it's showing after the children components and throwing above error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have a `<body>` component inside `div` component. That's not allowed as per HTML spec.

To fix that, modify the code like:

```
export default function RootLayout({children}:{children: React.ReactNode}){
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Navbar/>
      <div className={`${inter.className}`}>{children}</div>
    </html>
  )
}
```